# Is there a standard function that converts multi-line text into ASCII escaped form and vice versa?

Tags: text, escaping, ascii, multiline

UPDATE:

The right terminology has been `escaping` me. What I am looking for is a function that converts multi-line ASCII text into ASCII escaped form.

Is there a standard function that converts multi-line text into ASCII escaped form and vice versa?

I need to store multi-line text as `name=value` pairs, basically line `.ini` files, where `Value` is ASCII escaped text which fits on a single line, but I prefer the format that doesn't use numeric codes to express the non-printing characters if such a format exists.

The multi-line text can be long, up to 65K in length.

Comment: so you want to load .ini file to database table as text ? if that is the case , then you need escape string before database in code that loads data

Answer (score 1):

How about to use Base64?

Base64 is used to encode attached files of E-mail. Base64 can convert any kinds of data into strings made of characters upto 64 kinds (Upper and Lower case alphabet(52 kinds),0 to 9 (10 kinds), "-" and "+").

Large picture (over 1MB) can be encoded by Base64, so 65K charactes may not make trouble.

Comment: I have excluded base64 but the output must be still be readable

Answer (score 1):

In Windows `.ini` files, you can use the whole section to store multiline data.

```
[key1] 
several lines 
of data

[key2] 
another
```

Read it with [GetPrivateProfileSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724348(v=vs.85).aspx). To get a list of keys, use [GetPrivateProfileSectionNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724352(v=vs.85).aspx).